# Не кликабельная ссылка в письме после регистрации WordPress+WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

После попытки зарегистрироваться на сайте приходит письмо со следующим содержанием:

Имя пользователя: TestLogin Чтобы задать пароль, перейдите по следующей ссылке: сайт/wp-login.php.

И вот эта ссылка не кликабельная, перейти по ней невозможно, пользователи заводятся в базе, но клиенты не могут продолжить регистрацию.

Comment: Отключайте ве плагины, кроме WC, и проверяйте. Скорее всего, виноват мнимый плагин безопасности, вроде смены url страницы логина.

Comment: Стоят всего два плагина, WC и WCExchange

Comment: Это проблема почтовых клиентов. См в режиме текста.

Comment: @SeVlad другие письма которые формируются на сайте отправляются нормально с ссылками

Comment: Причём другие письма... Проблема давно известна и она именно в ссылке отправляемого ВП письма. Точнее в не понимании некоторыми почтовыми клиентами оформления. Ещё раз - см письмо в режиме текста. См https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb/